# How do I copy data from each record of one table into multiple records of another table related to the first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I'm working in SQL Server 2012.  I need to migrate data from one table to another, but I need to duplicate the data as well.  Here is the setup:

`Table A` has a 1 to many relationship to `Table B`.  Some of the data in each record in `Table A` needs to be moved to multiple records of `Table B` related to the `Table A` record.  Each record in `Table A` needs to copy its data into multiple records of `table B` for any records in `Table B` that links to a given `Table A` record.

I need a way to do this with one single `SQL UPDATE` if at all possible. And I need to understand how the SQL works.  I've not been able to find a way to do this through Google or searching SO.

```
Table A:
ID : int
Name : varchar2
Age : int
Type_ID : int
Rating : int

Table B:
ID : int
Table_A_ID : int
Name : varchar2
Age : int
Subject_ID : int
Note : varchar2
```

So in this example `Age` and `Name` need to be copied from `Table A` to all records of `Table B` that share `Table_A_ID` with `Table A`'s ID field.  Once the migration is successful, I will remove Name and `Age` from `Table A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating B is straightforward, simply JOIN the two tables together, indicate which table you intend updating, and map the columns across:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Age = a.Age, 
    b.Name = a.Name
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a
ON b.Table_A_ID = a.ID;
```

If you need to to also add missing rows, or delete removed rows, you might instead look at [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead to avoid needing to run separate `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements

Comment: Thank you. I had not realized a JOIN could be used as part of an UPDATE.  For some reason I thought that JOIN always resulted in a temporary view of the joined data, not a way to modify the actual joined tables.  This has solved my problem and is Accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help. The ["join in update" syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) isn't a standard, and differs between the various RDBMS's